# Triangle inequality for specific vector distance function

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, vectors

Define the metric d on $\mathbb{R}_n$ by d$(\vec{v},\vec{u})$=max{${|v_1−u_1|, |v_2−u_2|,...,|v_n−u_n|}$}. Show that this metric satisfies the property the "triangle inequality property" that d($\vec{v}$,$\vec{u}$) $\leq$ d($\vec{v}$, $\vec{w}$) + d($\vec{w}$,$\vec{u}$) for all v,u, w $\in \mathbb{R}_n$.
I was thinking maybe add $w_1$ to each term and then subtract it from each term in the expression defining d and then split each term up into i.e. $|v_1-w_1|$ and $|w_1+u_1|$ but I'm not sure how that would play out since they are all inside of a max{}

Comment: This question was already asked http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518249/triangle-inequality-for-uniquely-defined-vector-distance-function

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $d(v,u)=|v_j-u_j|$ then $|v_j-u_j|\leq |v_j-w_j|+|w_j-u_j|.$
This implies $|v_j-u_j|\leq \max_{i}|v_i-w_i|+\max_{k}|w_k-u_k|$